# jruby/activerecord-jdbc/tomcat/DB2 ready for enterprise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, db2, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am trying to introduce RoR to my company and I have two ways of doing so in my mind:

(1) rails/ibm_db2/passenger/DB2 - which is my preferable way but it is not really supported by company's infrastructure.
(2) jruby/activerecord-jdbc/tomcat/DB2 - probably easier way to migrate relying on current infrastructure and java libs IF I have a proof this is an enterprise ready technology.

Does anyone know if there is any prof that  jruby/aciverecord-jdbc-adapter/DB2/tomcat is mature enough for production? Are there any problems I should know about during Development/Deployment/Runtime?

My webapp is for a company intranet, around 200~400 active users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our company is using jruby on rails connecting to a DB2 database using activerecord-jdbc and Tomcat in our production environment, and we are extremely happy with it.  There have been some little challenges that we've had to solve because we've been using it alongside an existing java application, using a shared session, etc.  If you're building the entire application in rails, and not combining with JSPs, etc., then you'll be unlikely to run into these issues.

DB2 has worked quite well with a rails through activerecord-jdbc-adapter.  We have found that when we use a "find_by_sql" in an ActiveRecord model, that if the column selected does not exist in the table that the model references, it will simply treat the value for that column as a string (rather than correctly determining the type).  This results in some code that is a bit silly in our models that will simply parse the string into a typed object.  This may be fixed already in the newer activerecord-jdbc-adapter.  We have also created a few views in our database to help make this better.